# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This is my model class.when ruing my spring project it given this error
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize.
I did several solution but same error will given.Is any one can find what are the reason for getting that kind of error
this is my model class...

```
> import java.io.Serializable; import java.util.Date;
> 
> import javax.persistence.Basic; import javax.persistence.Column;
> import javax.persistence.Entity; import javax.persistence.FetchType;
> import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; import
> javax.persistence.GenerationType; import javax.persistence.Id; import
> javax.persistence.JoinColumn; import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
> import javax.persistence.NamedQueries; import
> javax.persistence.NamedQuery; import
> javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator; import javax.persistence.Table;
> import javax.persistence.Temporal; import
> javax.persistence.TemporalType; import
> javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
> 
> 
> @Entity @Table(name = "season_types" , schema = "unipointmain")
> @XmlRootElement @NamedQueries({
>     @NamedQuery(name = "SeasonTypes.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM SeasonTypes s"),
>     @NamedQuery(name = "SeasonTypes.findBySeasonName", query = "SELECT s FROM SeasonTypes s WHERE s.seasonName = :seasonName"),
>     @NamedQuery(name = "SeasonTypes.findBySeasonId", query = "SELECT s FROM SeasonTypes s WHERE s.seasonId = :seasonId"),
>     @NamedQuery(name = "SeasonTypes.findByStartDate", query = "SELECT s FROM SeasonTypes s WHERE s.startDate = :startDate"),
>     @NamedQuery(name = "SeasonTypes.findByEndDate", query = "SELECT s FROM SeasonTypes s WHERE s.endDate = :endDate"),
>     @NamedQuery(name = "SeasonTypes.findByComment", query = "SELECT s FROM SeasonTypes s WHERE s.comment = :comment")}) public class
> SeasonTypes implements Serializable {
>     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>     @Column(name = "season_name")
>     private String seasonName;
>     @Id //    @SequenceGenerator(name="pk_sequence",sequenceName="unipointmain.season_types_pk_seq",
> allocationSize=1)
> //    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="pk_sequence")
>     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="season_types_pk_seq")
>     @SequenceGenerator(name="season_types_pk_seq", sequenceName="unipointmain.season_types_pk_seq", allocationSize=1)
>     @Column(name = "season_id")
>     private Integer seasonId;
>     
>     @Column(name = "merchant_ref_id")     private Merchant merchant;
>     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_ref_id")
>     public Merchant getMerchant() {       return merchant;    }   public void setMerchant(Merchant merchant) {        this.merchant = merchant;   }
> 
>   @Column(name = "start_date")
>     private String startDate;
>     @Column(name = "end_date")
>     private String endDate;
>     @Column(name = "comment")
>     private String comment;
>     @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id", referencedColumnName = "offerid")
>     @ManyToOne
>     private Offer offerId;
>    
> 
>     public SeasonTypes() {
>     }
>     public SeasonTypes(Integer seasonId) {
>        this.seasonId = seasonId;
>     }
> 
>     public String getSeasonName() {
>         return seasonName;
>     }
> 
>     public void setSeasonName(String seasonName) {
>         this.seasonName = seasonName;
>     }
> 
>     public Integer getSeasonId() {
>         return seasonId;
>     }
> 
>     public void setSeasonId(Integer seasonId) {
>         this.seasonId = seasonId;
>     }
> 
>     public String getStartDate() {
>         return startDate;
>     }
> 
>     public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
>         this.startDate = startDate;
>     }
> 
>     public String getEndDate() {
>         return endDate;
>     }
> 
>     public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
>         this.endDate = endDate;
>     }
> 
>     public String getComment() {
>         return comment;
>     }
> 
>     public void setComment(String comment) {
>         this.comment = comment;
>     }
> 
>     public Offer getOfferId() {
>         return offerId;
>     }
> 
>     public void setOfferId(Offer offerId) {
>         this.offerId = offerId;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public int hashCode() {
>         int hash = 0;
>         hash += (seasonId != null ? seasonId.hashCode() : 0);
>         return hash;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public boolean equals(Object object) {
>         // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
>         if (!(object instanceof SeasonTypes)) {
>             return false;
>         }
>         SeasonTypes other = (SeasonTypes) object;
>         if ((this.seasonId == null && other.seasonId != null) || (this.seasonId != null && !this.seasonId.equals(other.seasonId))) {
>             return false;
>         }
>         return true;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public String toString() {
>         return "com.unipoint.test.SeasonTypes[ seasonId=" + seasonId + " ]";
>     }
>     
>      }
```

Comment: have you checked if Offer and Merchant (and all their fields) are serializable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class has to be serializable, as well as any classes that are given as arguments to your class.
Your issue probably lies `Merchant` or `Offer` not implementing the  serializable interface.

Hope this helps